# This action is unauthorized. con shinobi en laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5, users-roles

Despues de configurar shinobi, crear roles, permisos y asignarle un rol especifico a algun usuario, me da error al intentar acceder a la vista de la ruta de la cual ya tengo permiso, de alguna manera funciona porque estoy ocultando botones con con la directiva @can y evaluando el permiso que tengo, y me lo oculta pero cuando al acceder a la ruta no me da el error:

> This action is unauthorized.

No se porque la verdad, alguno podria ayudarme?

El código es el siguiente:

route web:

```
Route::get('users','UserController@index')->name('users.index')
    ->middleware('can:permission:users.index');
```

Configuracion del modelo user:

```
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Concerns\HasRolesAndPermissions;
class User extends Authenticatable
    {
   use Notifiable, HasRolesAndPermissions;
....
```

Probe agregando esto en el kernel.php

```
'has.role' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasRole::class,
'has.permission' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasPermission::class,
```

No se si es la version del shinobi que tiene problema o algo mas en la configuracion...

En base de datos puedo ver que tiene el rol y el rol tiene los permisos asignados correctamente. Agradeceria la ayuda.

Comment: amigo una pregunta como instalaste el paquete?, ya que a mi me aparece error con el composer require...

Comment: Hola @MatiasMuñoz bueno yo lo logre instalar como dice la pagina pero al final me sigui dando error por eso cambia a Spatie y me funciono mejor.

Comment: si, yo igual comencé a trabajar con spatie, shinobi tiene errores ojala lo solucionen

Answer (score 0):

Creo q el problema es en el registro de permission en el kernel.

'permission' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasPermission::class,

Para la validacion de permisos en rutas en la nueva version de shinobi no existe el archivo UserHasPermission... el modo rapido que encontre de solucionarlo es crear el archivo UserHasPermission.php en la carpeta \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\

```
<?php

namespace Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware;

use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Role;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class UserHasPermission
{
/**
* @var Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
*/
protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new UserHasPermission instance.
 *
 * @param Guard $auth
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Run the request filter.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Closure                 $closure
 * @param array|string             $permissions
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permissions)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        if (!$this->auth->user()->can($permissions)) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 403);
            }

            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
    } else {
        $guest = Role::whereSlug('guest')->first();

        if ($guest) {
            if (!$guest->can($permissions)) {
                if ($request->ajax()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 403);
                }

                abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Agregue al kernel.php en la sección de $routeMiddleware

   ```
    'has.role' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasRole::class,
   'has.permission' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasPermission::class,
   ```
2. en el archivo de rutas

   ```
   Route::name('admin.index')->get('/admin/index', 'Module\AdminController@index')->middleware('has.permission:admin.index');
   ```
3. agregue el archivo que menciona Cruz Vargas

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, prueba esto:

```
'has.permission' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
```

Esto ocurre porque para las versiones superiores del paquete Shinobi, usa el mismo middleware de Laravel  para las rutas, POR LO QUE NO REQUIERE EL DEL PAQUETE... Por eso no aparece *\Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\'**UserHasPermission**'::class*.

Respuesta dada en Laravel 6 y Shinobi 5.